# Why doesn't the return of my method work?

Tags: java

I have this assignment for a Java class I'm taking in college. I'm supposed to write a program that gets the length and width from a user and display the perimeter of a rectangle. Then, it needs to return the area. I have written the source code for it, but my IDE, Eclipse keeps saying that I'm using a voided method, therefore, it can't return.

Here is the source code:

```
/** Jason Delgado
 * SPC ID: 2051577
 * This program gets the length and width of a rectangle from the user, displays its perimeter,
 * and returns it area.
 */

package com.delgado;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane; //Gets the JOptionPane class
import java.text.DecimalFormat; //Gets the DecimalFormat class

public class Rectangle {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double length; // Holds length
    double width; // Holds width
    String input; // Holds input
    double area; // Holds area
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00"); // Holds format

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the length of the rectangle: ");
    length = Double.parseDouble(input);
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the width of the rectangle: ");
    width = Double.parseDouble(input);
    area = getArea(length, width);

    /** The method getArea() displays the perimeter of a rectangle and returns the area
     * @perm num1 Holds the length
     * @perm num2 Holds the width
     * @return Returns the area of a rectangle
     */

    public static double getArea(double num1, double num2){
        double perimeter; // Holds perimeter
        perimeter = (num1 * 2) + (num2 * 2);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The perimeter of the rectangle is: " + formatter.format(perimeter));

        return num1 * num2;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: You probably defined your method as `public void myMethod(int x, int y) {...}`, so it can't have a return. Change `void` to the return type you want.

Comment: pls post the part of your code with errors.

Comment: if the method has a return type of void that's another way of telling the compiler "this method returns nothing"... the type in the function declaration must match the type returned from the function (or a superclass of the returned type but that's another story).

Comment: Also, if you want a more precise or exact answer, post your code so that we can be better in our answers, rather than making assumptions.

Comment: Please start by reading the Help Center to learn how to ask a proper question. Post only relevant code. Post exact error messages. Do your research first. (The error and the solution are everywhere on SO or Google.)

Comment: Now that you've added your code it looks as if you've either mucked up your braces when posting, or nested your function inside Main. Java does not support nested functions. Move the getArea function outside of the main method body.

Comment: You definitely do not get the error you are reporting with the code you posted.

Comment: Thank you @MattCoubrough that was the problem. I had my method nested inside the main. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Since you've added your code, I have edited my answer:

It looks like your `getArea` method is inside your main. Move it outside.

```
public class Rectangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ....
    }

    public static double getArea(double num1, double num2) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

syntax for a method :

```
   access_modifier return_type method_name(parameters) {
        ...
        return value_under_that_return_type;
   }
```

place your methods in this order:

```
... getArea() {...}

... main() {...}
```

You shouldn't be nesting functions.

Comment: You have nested your method in the main method. You should move getArea out.